# How to optimize affinity propagation results?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was wondering if anybody knows anything deeper than what I do about the Affinity Propagation clustering algorithm in the python scikit-learn package?

All I know right now is that I input an "affinity matrix" (affmat), which is calculated by applying a heat kernel transformation to the "distance matrix" (distmat). The distmat is the output of a previous analysis step I do. After I obtain the affmat, I pass that into the algorithm by doing something analogous to:

```
af = AffinityPropagation(affinity = 'precomputed').fit(affmat)
```

On one hand, I appreciate the simplicity of the inputs. On the other hand, I'm still not sure if I've got the input done correctly?

I have tried evaluating the results by looking at the Silhouette scores, and frequently (but not a majority of the time) I am getting scores close to zero or in the negative ranges, which indicate to me that I'm not getting clusters that are 'naturally grouped'. This, to me, is a problem.

Additionally, when I observe some of the plots, I'm getting weird patterns of clustering, such as the image below, where I clearly see 3 clusters of points, but AP is giving me 10:

[image: Visual inspection tells you there's 3 clusters, but AP returns 10]

I also see other graphs like this, where the clusters overlap a lot.:

[image: Visual inspection won't tell you how many clusters there are, but the clusters look pretty much overlapping]

How are the cluster centers' euclidean coordinates identified? I notice when I put in percent values (99.2, 99.5 etc.), rather than fraction values (0.992, 0.995 etc.), the x- and y-axes change in scale from [0, 1] to [0, 100] (but of course the axes are scaled appropriately such that I'm getting, on occasion, [88, 100] or [92, 100] and so on).

Sorry for the rambling here, but I'm having quite a hard time understanding the underpinnings of the python implementation of the algorithm. I've gone back to the original paper and read it, but I don't know how the manipulate it in the scikit-learn package to get better clustering.

Comment: That one line of code seems fine, but for the rest it's hard to tell what's going wrong. Is that plot showing the points in Euclidean space? If so, can you try clustering with `1./distmat` or `-distmat` as the affinity matrix just to check?

Comment: Hi @larsmans, I have tried (1-distmat) as the affinity matrix as well, and the plots look slightly different but of the same general shape. How do we tell if the plot is showing points in Euclidean space?

Comment: What I mean is: what did you plot, the original points or some transformation of them?

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me share some more code here. I based the code I was looking off the affinity propagation sample code. The URL is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html#example-cluster-plot-affinity-propagation-py).

The plotting code is identical to the sample code provided, except I changed variable names where appropriate.